# custom setting coverage in test class

Tags: unit-test, customsetting

how to cover custom setting in test class and how to get `getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId())`

this is my class code

```
Profile_Oons__c contentesetup = Profile_Oons__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like normal SObjects, your Test Context doesn't have access to the custom setting records already in the database.

You can perfectly, insert a new Custom Setting record, in your test context like you would normally do with an SObject

```
Whatever_custom_setting__c setting = new Whatever_custom_setting__c();
setting.Name = 'Test Setting';
setting.Value__c = 'Whatever';
insert setting;
```

and then your function should return the newly created test setting.

Comment: my question is how to get from query on customsettings

Comment: You should insert the expected value, test and assert. Then insert a bad value then retest and assert. This means your test will run successfully if your code is deployed to a SalesForce org where you have not configured the custom setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link to do query on custom setting:

[Retrieving Values from Custom Settings](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12835/retrieving-values-from-custom-settings)

If you need to create custom setting in Test class, then I am much satisfy with the @Developer__c comments.

Hope it resolves your problem.